# Rails credentials do not update on new deploys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My rails app can only see credentials that were already in my `config/credentials.yml.enc` file when I first deployed my app. Any subsequent secrets that I've made or changes to existing ones are not picked up.

Trying to troubleshoot my issue, from a `rails c` console on my production server, if I evaluate

```
Rails.application.credentials.content_path
```

I get

```
#<Pathname:/var/www/app_name/config/credentials.yml.enc>
```

`app_name/config/credentials.yml.enc` contains the encrypted credentials file in its initial state as it was upon first deploy. I feel like

```
Rails.application.credentials.content_path
```

should evaluate to

```
#<Pathname:/var/www/app_name/*current*/config/credentials.yml.enc>
```

(`*` for emphasis). I use capistrano to deploy. My `deploy.rb` contains:

```
append :linked_files, "config/secrets.yml", "config/database.yml", "config/master.key"

append :linked_dirs, "bin", "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system", "vendor/bundle"
```

How can I get my app to recognize credentials from my current release?